# Batch Script: Replace One Variable with Another

Tags: batch-file, replace

OK basicly what I am trying to do is make a script that will update one variable with another.

I have already created all of the script so it pulls the new data from the registry and sets it, now i just need it to update an old variable.

Example script

```
set current_shockwave_version=1
set current_flash_version=1

FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer" /v CurrentVersion ') DO SET Installed_Flash_Version=%%B
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Shockwave 11\currentupdateversion" ') DO SET Installed_Shockwave_Version=%%B
```

Now i want to replace the value of current_shockwave_version & current_flash_version with the variables pulled from the registry. There will be a bunch of admins using  this script and im trying to add a easy update function so they can just run this replace function on a computer that is fully updated.

Comment: So what's the problem? Is it not working? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what result do you want, but I assume that you only want to read the registry value only once and update then the lines.

```
set current_shockwave_version=1
set current_flash_version=1
```

With the new values.
The easiest way is to move the two lines into a *config.bat* file, then you can use something like

```
call config.bat
echo current_flash_version = %current_flash_version%

:UpdateValues
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer" /v CurrentVersion ') DO SET Installed_Flash_Version=%%B
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Shockwave 11\currentupdateversion" ') DO SET Installed_Shockwave_Version=%%B
(
  echo set current_shockwave_version=%Installed_Shockwave_Version%
  echo set current_flash_version=%Installed_Flash_Version%
) > config.bat
```

**EDIT:** To the comment of replacing in the same batch file
It's not a good idea to replace the values in the same batch file, as to do this you need to rewrite the batch while it's running.
This can be done, but it's tricky, especially if the length of the values will not be the same, the batch will work a bit unreliable.

You could solve it when you move the setting of the *database* values to the end of the file, but IMO it's not the best idea to change the currently running batch.

```
@echo off
call :setValues
echo current_flash_version = %current_flash_version%
call :UpdateValues
echo new current_flash_version = %current_flash_version%
exit /b

:UpdateValues
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer" /v CurrentVersion ') DO SET Installed_Flash_Version=%%B
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Shockwave 11\currentupdateversion" ') DO SET Installed_Shockwave_Version=%%B
REM ** Copy and modify the own batch
findstr /v /r "##DB##$" "%~f0" > "%~f0.tmp"
(
  (echo set "current_shockwave_version=%Installed_Shockwave_Version%" ^& REM ##DB##)
  (echo set "current_flash_version=%Installed_Flash_Version%" ^& REM ##DB##)
) >> "%~f0.tmp"
(
  copy "%~f0.tmp" "%~f0"
  del "%~f0.tmp"
)
call :setValues
exit /b

:setValues
set "current_shockwave_version=1" & REM ##DB##
set "current_flash_version=1" & REM ##DB##
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I want to do a replace function to replace the original value of flash version with the version number pulled from the registry. When the script runs it will already have the version set. I am trying to add a function that will pull the version numbers from the registry and replace the number for the variable current_software_version (ex. flash & shockwave). Also i need all of this to be contained within the single batch file. I have seen some people play with the findstr function but i havn't found a good example of it that does what i want easily.

Comment: I will be planning on restarting the batch file after the edits take place. The point of this function will be to make it an automated process so that when other admins try to update the script they will not accidentally break the script and/or something else.
edit: also the values *should* be the same length.

Comment: But the values can become longer, as sometimes a version can be get greater 10

Comment: true but they way they are stored in the registry is pretty consistent. Anyways i ran your script and am not having much luck, it simeply repeats the updated value is the same as the initial length

Comment: Do you removed the `REM` in front of the copy/del statements? But you could first look into your file appended with `.tmp`

Comment: yes it does not export the data pulled from the registry.

`:UpdateValues
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=    " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer" /v CurrentVersion ') DO SET Installed_Flash_Version=%%B
REM ** Copy and modify the own batch
findstr /v /r "##DB##$" "%~f0" > "%~f0.tmp"
(
  (echo set "current_flash_version=%Installed_Flash_Version%" ^& ##DB##)
) >> "%~f0.tmp"
(
  copy "%~f0.tmp" "%~f0"
  rem del "%~f0.tmp"
)
call :setValues
exit /b

:setValues
set "current_flash_version=" & ##DB##'`

Comment: You should remove the `delims=     `, as they can't work on Win7 and Vista, as they uses spaces only XP used TAB's

Comment: here is the new updated source code                                    set "current_flash_version=1" & REM ##DB##set "current_shockwave_version=" & REM ##DB##
set "current_flash_version=" & REM ##DB##

Comment: I suppose that your second req Query will fail, as you didn't define any `/v`

Comment: still pulling nothing
set "current_shockwave_version=" & REM ##DB##
set "current_flash_version=" & REM ##DB##

Comment: Do you have tested the the variables `Installed_Shockwave_Version` and `Installed_Flash_Version` do they contain any values?